# Internal Types for .NET Plugin Loading

Tags: .net-core, plugins, f#

I'm developing a plugin-loading system for my F# .NET 5 app, following [this Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support). I wanted to provide an interface `ICore` that would have some internal, opaque state type that I would provide an interface for manipulating.

In Scala, I might do this like

```scala
trait ICore {
  type State

  def reset: State
}
```

and then call this method like

```scala
def resetCoreState(c: Core): c.State = c.reset
```

and implement a core like

```scala
object StringCore extends ICore {
  override type State = String

  override def reset: String = ""
}
```

however F# doesn't have this feature.

How should I design my interface,

```ml
type ICore() =
  interface

  // abstract type State

  abstract method reset : State

  end

let resetCoreState : ???

type StringCore() = ???
```

so that plugins can manage their own state?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any simple way to make the state type opaque, but here's how I would define these types in F#:

```
type ICore<'state> =
    abstract member Reset : 'state

type StringCore() =
    interface ICore<string> with
        member __.Reset = ""

let resetCoreState (core : ICore<_>) =
    core.Reset
```

Comment: `def` in Scala is just like `let` in F#. `c.State` is a return type. So, the F# equivalent would be like `let resetCoreState <'state> (core : ICore<'state>) : 'state = core.Reset`

Comment: Ah, OK. Then the top half of my answer applies. I've edited it accordingly.